# How to delete last symbol from string in SQL Server. In case it is a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops

I have a query

```
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN   
   SET @message =' ,' + CASE WHEN @year < 10 THEN 'socyr0' ELSE 'socyr' END + CAST(@year AS varchar) + ' as '+ CAST(@sql AS varchar) + ','  
   PRINT @message   
   FETCH NEXT FROM SocioCursor INTO @year
   SET @sql = @sql + 1 
END
```

and result is few strings like

```
socyr08 as 2006,  
socyr09 as 2007,  
socyr10 as 2008,  
socyr11 as 2009,  
socyr12 as 2010,
```

What should I change to get

```
socyr08 as 2006,  
socyr09 as 2007,  
socyr10 as 2008,  
socyr11 as 2009,  
socyr12 as 2010
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are expecting them in a single row of text or not. I think you could do it like below without a cursor.

Please adjust `variable length` *and* `right function` as required and remove `char(13)` if you need a single row without line breaks.

[Sql-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebeb/7)

```
declare @sql int = 2006, @message varchar(500)

select @message = isnull(@message + ',' + char(13), '') + 
                  'socyr' + right(100 + year, 2) + ' as ' + 
                  convert(varchar(4), @sql), 
                  @sql = @sql +1
from T

select @message


| COLUMN_0     |
----------------
socyr01 as 2006,
socyr02 as 2007,
socyr09 as 2008,
socyr10 as 2009,
socyr11 as 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and print the `@message` variable **outside** the loop.

In the loop you simply add a piece to it, like this: `@message = @message + ...`

Then, **before** printing it, you need to trim the last comma character:

```
@message = SUBSTRING ( @message, 1, LEN (@message) - 1 )
```